# How to prevent ASP.NET ReportViewer from displaying the default DateTime value when the field is null?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

When using ReportViewer and binding a column in a table with a nullable DateTime field it displays the default (DateTime) if the field is null.  Is there any expression to not display the default value of the DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!MyDateField.Value), Parameters!EmptyFullDateTime.Value, Format(Fields!MyDateField.Value, Parameters!FormatFullDateTimePattern.Value))

And I have EmptyFullDataTime parameter defined as --/--/---- --:--
And FormatFullDateTimePattern will be set depending on the culture. (e.g. dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)

MyDateField is a System.DateTime? type ( nullable )

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your expression on the textbox that contains the datefield value

```
=IIF(Field!dateField.Value == DateTime.MinValue, String.Empty, Field!dateField.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(Fields!PaymentDate Is Nothing, "", Fields!PaymentDate.Value)
```

Comment: Accidently must have hit the down vote button. I thought your answer was actually very useful.